# Taking the Derivative Matrix of an equation

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I want to verify that I have taken the derivative matrix of an equation correctly.

For $S(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)= (r^2\cos^2\theta-r^2\sin^2\theta, 2r^2\sin\theta \cos\theta)$

I have $DS(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$= $$\begin{bmatrix}2r\cos\theta & 2r\sin\theta \\ 2r\sin\theta & 2r\cos\theta \end{bmatrix} $$

Is this correct?

Comment: No this is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for responding, how so? Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The correct definition is

$$DS = \begin{bmatrix}
 \partial_1 S^1& \partial_2 S^1\\ 
 \partial_1 S^2 & \partial_2 S^2 
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $S(r,\theta) = (S^1,S^2) = (r^2\cos^2\theta-r^2\sin^2\theta, 2r^2 \sin\theta \cos\theta).$

Therefore,

\begin{align}DS &= \begin{bmatrix}
2r(\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta )& -4r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta\\ 
4r\cos\theta\sin\theta & 2r^2(\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta)
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
2r(\cos2\theta )& -2r^2\sin2\theta\\ 
2r\sin2\theta & 2r^2(\cos2\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}